# values not getting loaded when page is loaded

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I'm writing a web app where when the index.jsp is opened, there are values that have to be pulled from database and displayed as header. In my current scenario, when i run the project from my eclipse it is showing the values, and when i try to do the same by exporting the project to war and deploying it from tomcat separately, it is not working. Below are the files.

**Index.jsp**

```
<%@page import="org.bean.UserBean"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myCssFile.css">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function enableSubmit() {
        document.getElementById("getCase").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("submitButton").disabled = false;
    }
    function enableGetCase() {
        document.getElementById("getCase").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("submitButton").disabled = true;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header" id="header">
        <form id="form1"></form>
    </div>

    <div class="bodytag">
        <form method="get" action="GetData">
            <input type="Submit" value="Get Case" name="getCase" id="getCase"
                onclick="enableSubmit()" />
            <table>

                <tr>
                    <td>Case Number</td>
                    <td><input id="Text1" type="text" value="" /></td>

                    <td>Case Owner</td>
                    <td><input id="Text6" type="text" value="" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Source</td>
                    <td><input id="Text2" type="text" /></td>
                    <td>Status</td>
                    <td><input id="Text7" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style2">Issue</td>
                    <td class="auto-style2"><input id="Text3" value="" type="text" /></td>
                    <td class="auto-style2">Reason</td>
                    <td class="auto-style2"><input id="Text8" value="" type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Date/Time Opened</td>
                    <td><input id="Text4" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td>Age(Days)</td>
                    <td><input id="Text10" type="text" value="" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Resolution</td>
                    <td><select id="Select1" name="D1">
                            <option></option>
                    </select></td>
                    <td>Final Status</td>
                    <td><select id="Select2" name="D2">
                            <option value="     "></option>
                    </select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Start Time</td>
                    <td><input id="Text5" type="text" value="Start Time" /></td>
                    <td>End Time</td>
                    <td><input id="Text9" type="text" value="end Time" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="button" value="Submit" name="submitButton"
                id="submitButton" disabled="disabled" onClick="enableGetCase()" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="SampleJS.js"></script>
</body>
```

**Servlet**

```
package org.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.DAO.GetTheCountsDAO;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import net.sf.json.JSONObject;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class GetTheCounts
 */
@WebServlet("/GetTheCounts")
public class GetTheCounts extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public GetTheCounts() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        GetTheCountsDAO getTheCountsDAO = new GetTheCountsDAO();
        try {
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            int excelCount = getTheCountsDAO.getTotalFromExcel();
            int DAOCount = getTheCountsDAO.getTotalFromDB();
            double getEffeciency = getTheCountsDAO.getEffeciency();
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("DAOCount", DAOCount);
            jsonObject.put("excelCount", excelCount);
            jsonObject.put("effeciency", getEffeciency);
            String json = new Gson().toJson(jsonObject);
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            System.out.println("Returned String is " + json);
            response.getWriter().write(json);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**GetTheCountsDAO**

```
package org.DAO;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import org.code.general.DBConnection;

public class GetTheCountsDAO {
    DBConnection dbConnection = new DBConnection();
    int excelCount, DBCount, effeciency;
    double timeTaken = -1.0;

    public int getTotalFromExcel() throws Exception {
        Connection conn = dbConnection.getConn();
        Statement stmt = dbConnection.getStmt();
        ResultSet rs = dbConnection.getRs();
        String excelPath = dbConnection.getExcelPath();
        String queryString = null;
        dbConnection.createClassForNameForExcel();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DBQ=" + excelPath + "; READONLY=FALSE;");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        queryString = "SELECT COUNT(*) as CNT from [report1448039568905$]";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(queryString);
        rs.next();
        excelCount = rs.getInt("CNT");
        rs.close();
        return excelCount;
    }

    public int getTotalFromDB() throws Exception {
        Connection conn = dbConnection.getConn();
        Statement stmt, stmt1 = dbConnection.getStmt();
        ResultSet rs, rs1 = dbConnection.getRs();

        String queryString, queryString1 = null;
        dbConnection.createClassForNameForSQLServer();
        String userName = "sa";
        String password = "T!ger123";
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://U0138039-TPD-A\\SQLEXPRESS;DatabaseName=TEST";
        dbConnection.createClassForNameForSQLServer();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        queryString = "SELECT COUNT(*) as CNT from statusTable";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(queryString);
        rs.next();
        DBCount = rs.getInt("CNT");
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        stmt1 = conn.createStatement();
        queryString1 = "select sum([Time Taken(minutes)]) as timeTaken from statusTable";
        rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery(queryString1);
        rs1.next();
        timeTaken = rs1.getDouble(1);
        stmt1.close();
        conn.close();
        return DBCount;
    }

    public double getEffeciency() throws Exception {
        double getAtcualProcessed = DBCount / timeTaken;
        double effeciency = (getAtcualProcessed / 8) * 100;
        return Math.round(effeciency * 100) / 100.00;
    }

}
```

**SampleJS.js**

```
$(window).load(
        function() {
            $("#form1").on(
                    'submit',
                    function(e) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type : "get",
                            url : "GetTheCounts",
                            data : $(this).serialize(),
                            success : function(msg) {
                                console.log(JSON.stringify(msg));
                                var $span = $('<span class="totalTime">')
                                        .appendTo($('#header'));
                                $span.append("Status: (Worked/Total) -")
                                        .append("\t\t\t\t\t").append(
                                                msg.DAOCount).append("/")
                                        .append(msg.excelCount);
                                var $span1 = $('<span class="effeciency">')
                                        .appendTo($('#header'));
                                $span1.append("Effeciency : ").append(
                                        msg.effeciency);
                            }
                        });
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }).submit();
        });
```

And **CSS**

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 1em;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 3em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    background: #ff8800;
}

.bodytag {
    margin-top: 7em;
    display: table;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    padding: 3em;
}

span.totalTime {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

span.effeciency {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: auto;
    margin-right: 2em;
    top: 30px;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#getCase {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    display: block;
}

#submitButton {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 1em;
    display: block;
}

#postData {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 1em;
    display: block;
}

table {
    border-spacing: 10px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

please let me know where am I going wrong. and how can I fix this. This is working fine in Eclipse browser but not in external browser.

Below are my outputs

Deployed in Eclipse

[image]

Deployed as WAR externally in Tomcat web GUI

[image]

Here for Eclipse I used Tomcat 8.0 and externally I used 7.0 and while exporting to WAR I've unchecked the Server Compatibility check box.

In Eclipse, the port is 8080 and For the external Tomcat I've used the 9090 (Just to make sure that there is no confusion).

Comment: Can you please check in the developer console tat SampleJs.js file is loaded by the browser?

Comment: Hi @Lathy, this was helpful, there were some JSON libraries missing. Thanks again

Comment: You mean js files were missing?

Comment: @Lathy, all JSON supported files.